# Is it secure to derive multiple keys from one password?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, hash

**Problem**

My application (which I will be writing in C#) uses a key derivation method (Rfc2898DeriveBytes, 4000 iterations) along with a salt to generate a "hash" of a password. This hash is then sent to a database so that the user can use that password in the future to authenticate to their account.

So far that should be secure, but after that, I want to use Rfc2898DeriveBytes on the same password to generate a key which can then be used **for encryption**. Now the way I was going to do that was to use 5000 iterations of the same method to get a different key, but I am concerned that if the hash stored in the database was compromised (or I was forced to reveal it) it would be possible to derive the second key somehow. Is that possible?

**Potential Solutions**

- Ideally I would like to use the same salt, but would using a
  different one fix the problem?
- What about using SHA for the database hash and Rfc for the encryption
  key?
- Appending a unique but hard coded string (like "website" and "encryption" respectively) to each before deriving the key. (Damien_the_Unbeliever)
- Generate a double-length key, and use the first half of the derived key for authentication, and the second half for encryption. (erickson)

I would appreciate any advice on how best to improve this process. I would post code but I haven't written it yet.

Comment: If one of the hashes is compromised, and as a result, the password is determined, then the user can access either functionality, by definition, because they have the plaintext password. Of course, if they can't get the plaintext password from the hash because your hash method + salting is beyond their capability to crack, then it shouldn't be a problem. If the malicious user can crack it and get the plaintext, they can access anything that passwords gives access to, no matter what you do.

Comment: Yeah, my concern is if one key can be used to derive the other. For example: (I'll test this when I get the chance) could the 4,000 iteration version simply be hashed an extra 1,000 times to derive the 5,000 version?

Comment: So what if it can be.  The whole *point* of hashing is that having the hash alone is meaningless.  Someone can't just send you the hash of their password and login, if they could then there's no advantage of using hashing in the first place over using a plaintext password, beyond protecting users that use the same password on multiple systems from a malicious system admin.

Comment: That's normally true, but the first key is a "hash" for logging into the website while the second key is being used for encryption. The second key must remain private at all costs because it can decrypt important data.

Comment: Just prepend the text `Password` to the text of the password for one usage, and `Encryption` to the text of the password for the other (or, in general, just add some fixed text that's significantly different to each usage)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's a great point. Doing that should have the same effect as using a separate salt except that I wouldn't have to store the extra salt.

Comment: @Servy a compromised hash with a strong hashing algorithm with strong, solid salting practices usually takes the form of a collision, not a plain text discovery. In other words, an attacker won't just be looking up Razick's plaintext passwords in a rainbow table - it would have to be brute forced with no guarantee that the discovered plaintext is the same plain text the user originally entered. A collision with one algorithm is almost certainly not a collision with the same plaintext in a separate algorithm, and with separate salts, a twin collision like that is nigh impossible.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is exactly what a salt is.  In this case it's using a constant salt, rather than a variable one, but a salt nonetheless.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but a salt should be unique for each password, this way I can use a unique salt *and* a hard coded constant salt.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, but if you've got a function that accepts two inputs - a string and a (fixed width) salt - and you want to use it to derive *two* outputs, and the user wants to use a single salt, then I'd just vary the string input as I suggested. It's a reasonably well known technique for deriving multiple keys from a single password

Comment: @Razick My point is simply that it is a salt.  It's not *like* a salt or *similar* to a salt.  It is the very definition of a salt.  While a salt should, generally, not be constant, it is still a salt even if it is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***For easy reference, I'm compiling the advice I was given into one answer.***

**Iteration Count**

Although this wasn't part of my question erickson pointed out that 5,000 iterations for Rfc2898DeriveBytes (a PBKDF2 method for C#) is far too few and recommended at least 50,000.

After looking elsewhere for more information, it seems that between 50,000 and 1,000,000 is a good number of iterations, but keep in mind there is an inverse relation between speed and security here: As the number of iterations increases so does security, and the amount of time it takes to derive the key (which is why it's more secure).

**Solutions**

Although according to erickson the first key could not be used to determine the second, it does make a brute-force attack easier. Therefore, any of the following solutions could be used to address the issue:

- Generate a double-length key, and use the first half of the derived key for authentication, and the second half for encryption. (erickson)
- Use a separate salt for each key.
- Appending a unique but hard coded salt (like "website" and "encryption" respectively) to each before deriving the key. A unique salt should be used in addition.(Damien_the_Unbeliever)

**Rejected Solutions**

- SHA_512 is too fast to be secure for my purposes (and for most purposes in which hashes are used). Using multiple iterations can help, but it is far more secure to use a PBKDF2 method such as Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

**Conclusion**

Thank you everyone for your help, if you have any further insight please comment and I'll do my best to add it.

Answer (score 3):

You can derive multiple keys from one password.

Whether you use different salts for different purposes, or generate a longer key and use parts of it for different purposes, depends on whether you need the different keys at the same time. For example, suppose a user logs in, and then expects to be able to encrypt and decrypt content without re-entering their password. In that case, it would be more efficient to generate a double-length key, and use the first half of the derived key for authentication, and the second half for encryption. Generating two keys with different salts would take about twice as long.

On the other hand, if the user is expected to enter the password for authentication, and then some other time for encryption, you might as well select two salts.

With your proposal, revealing the authentication hash stored in the database wouldn't lead immediately to a compromise. That is, you couldn't simply iterate the hash function; each iteration of PBKDF2 uses the password as input. But it does mean that only 1000 iterations are required to test a password as an encryption key, and that provides almost no protection from a dictionary attack.

By the way, 5000 iterations is not nearly enough. 50000 iterations would be a good start.

Comment: I thought I had read somewhere that 4,000 is the standard "best practice" recommendation. I am very glad that you pointed out my error!

Answer (score 2):

Using a different salt between the two calls of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` solves your problem.

Think of it this way, two different users use the same password, will knowing the hash of one compromise the other? Only if the two users use the same salt!

What you are doing is no different, just use two good salts for both uses of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and you will be fine. No need to change the number of iterations for the two methods, just change the salt.

There is no reason you need to re-use the salt, the salt is not secret information. Most implementations of file encryption puts the salt (also known as the `IV`) at the front of the encrypted blob.

---

For your other solution "*What about using SHA for the database hash and Rfc for the encryption key?*" This is a **VERY** bad idea. Just using SHA for the database means it will be much easier for them to get the original password, then they can use that easier task to do the harder task of decrypting the Rfc based one.

Comment: SHA is easy to crack? I'm of course also assuming the OP means to say SHA2.

Comment: Yes, SHA vs a proper PBKDF is magnitudes easier. It is the entire point of a PBKDF to make hashing **slow**. You can brute force SHA in the Mega-hashes or Giga-hases per second range while a PBDFK with proper itteration count should be in the low 100's per second.

Comment: I believe that the salt and initialization vectors are different and serve different purposes. AES_256 for example uses both as I think most algorithms do.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I would use multiple iterations of SHA_512 but I think a unique salt would be safer.

Comment: Oh, PBKDF is definitely more secure against brute force attacks, but SHA2 isn't "easy", assuming a strong password, and even SHA1 attacks are thus far only theoretical. Anyway, removing "easy" and perhaps just say one is better would get my upvote.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I changed to "easier" and "harder"